# AWS Cloud9: Can you Stop an Environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

I have 3 instances running in my Cloud9 environment.

However, to save money, I'd like to stop them overnight. If I stop the instances, another 3 get fired up.

I can delete the environment (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/delete-environment.html ) but I'd like to keep the state of my work.

Is there a way of stopping the instances so you don't get charged for 100% uptime?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Cloud9 EC2 environment – Enables you to launch a new Amazon EC2 instance that Cloud9 connects to. By default, these instances stop 30 minutes after you close the IDE and start automatically when you open the IDE.
You can read this [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/faqs/)

Comment: I closed the IDE 40 minutes ago and they're still running.

Comment: Try close EC2 instances that CLoud9 is connected to. Or try from Cloud9 terminal to send command: "sudo poweroff"

Comment: OK, figured it out. The K8s cluster I'd fired up from that console were being restarted. It seems they're not included as part of the IDE instances.